# Qt widget shape from image

Tags: image, qt, widget, pyqt, shapes

How can I create a widget or window that will be just a transparent image?
I mean something like in this program: [sakura script player](http://ssp.shillest.net/)
What i tried is:

```
label = QtGui.QLabel(None,
                    QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('c:\transparent.png'))
label.setScaledContents(True)

label.show()
```

but it generates just a rectangle window, in spite of image's transparency

Comment: forgot to mention, im using PyQt4|Python3.2|Windows7, but trying to get some 'crossplatform' code

Comment: OK, solved it! Here's example (plane.png contents alpha-channel):
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('c:\plane.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.setMask(pixmap.mask())
shitty formatting system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a combination of [`QWidget::setMask()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#setMask) and one of the functions that create `QBitmap` masks from `QPixmap`s:

- [createHeuristicMask()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qpixmap.html#createHeuristicMask)
- [createMaskFromColor()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qpixmap.html#createMaskFromColor)
- [mask()](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qpixmap.html#mask) (should probably be called `createMaskFromAlpha()` instead).

There used to be an xpenguin-like example in the Qt distribution, but they replaced it with a shaped clock (if you have Qt 3.3 around, check out `examples/tux/tux.cpp`).